# Express : TypeError: user.company.pull is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean

I'd like to remove an object element from my user object, I'm using pull to remove it, but it returns

> TypeError: user.company.pull is not a function

```
router.put('/reset', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next)=> {
    user = req.user;
    var id_student = user.id;
    var id_company = user.company;
    var results = [];
    User.findById(id_student, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send({message: "Error"});
        }
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(404).send({message: "User Not Found"});            
        }
        user.company.pull({'company': id_company});
        res.send(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: You forgot `var` use `"use strict"`

Comment: Where I can put it on?

Answer (score -1):

Use `'use strict';` at top of `js` files.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode for more information

Check if variable `user` has property `copmany` or not and handle it.

Use this condition

```
if(!user || !user.hasOwnProperty('company')) {
    return res.status(404).send({message: "User Not Found"});            
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue at hand. The `user` definition on line 2 will be out of scope by the time the code hits `User.findById`, as there's a `user` parameter defined in the callback.

Comment: So just the second line is wrong in answer, right? @JoshMcMillan

Comment: But it give me TypeError: Cannot read property 'pull' of null

Comment: does `user` have property `company`? you checked it?? log `user` before calling `pull`

Answer (score -1):

Effectively, `user.company.pull` is probably undefined, rather than the function that you're looking for.

If `user.company` doesn't exist, then `user.company` is going to be `undefined`, and there's not a `pull` method defined on `undefined`. This means that you're effectively trying to call `undefined.pull({'company': whatever})`, which will never work.

Try adding a guard to ensure that you have a company attached to a user, in the same way you check to ensure that the user exists. For example:

```
if (!user.company) {
    return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Company not found'});
}
```